A representation of positive matrix
Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert space. Let $-\frac{1}{2}<r<0.$ Denote $c_p:=\int_{0}^\infty\frac{t^r}{1+t}dt.$ Suppose $A$ be a positive invertible operator in $B(\mathcal H).$ Is it true that $A^r=c_p^{-1}\int_{0}^\infty t^r(t+A)^{-1}dt$?

Since $A$ is positive, the C*-algebra generated by it is isomoprhic to $C(sp(A))$. Then, the answer is true since the integral converges on sp(A) uniformly.

@Boris. The integral is not with respect to the spectral measure but with respect ro the Lebesgue measure.

It is not a problem. The function inside the integral is a function with values in $C(sp(A))$. You can thing about it as a function on $[0, \infty)\times sp(A)$. And then you take the integral in the first variable $t$.
